# Can machine learning be used in this scenario?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm keen to learn more about machine learning, as I feel it could be something that might have its uses in my place of work. I write PC software that controls scientific instruments, and one of its functions involves measuring a voltage every 100ms for (say) 10 seconds, then plotting this on a chart in my software. The chart typically consists of a single peak, although its shape will vary depending on how well "tuned" the instrument is.

Using this chart (which keeps plotting over and over again), an engineer will tune the instrument to achieve the best peak shape possible. While there is no such thing as a "perfect" peak, the requirement is to:-

- Have a flat top (some noise is normal)
- Have (near) vertical sides
- Have the peak centred in the chart (on a poorly tuned instrument the peak will be shifted to the left or right).

Tuning of the instrument involves configuring many different parameters in the PC software which sets voltages and pressures within the instrument, all of which can affect the peak shape. Tuning is trial and error, with the engineer trying ranges of values for each parameter, and can take days or even weeks due to the many permutations involved.

I had been wondering if ML could be used to implement an "auto-tune" feature in the software, but I'm struggling to know which ML concepts, algorithms, and so on, I should be considering - and where to start! At the same time I don't want to be accused of trying to find a problem to solve with ML just for the sake of it.

Comment: Can? Certainly! Will it be good? No idea, depends on many factors. That said, it seems to me as if the criteria you're looking at can be defined precisely and checked deterministically.